# 403 error on index file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, 403-forbidden

When I try to access index.py in my server root through http://domain/, I get a 403 Forbidden error, but when I can access it through http://domain/index.py. In my server logs it says "Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/index.py". However, my httpd.conf entry for that directory is the same as the ones for other directories, and getting to index.py works fine. My permissions are set to 755 for index.py.

I also tried making a php file and naming it index.php, and it works from both domain/ and domain/index.php.

Here is my httpd.conf entry:

```
<Directory /var/www>
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
AddHandler cgi-script .py
Options +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.py
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a silly question, but did you restart your web server process after modifying httpd.conf? Sometimes I forget to do that...

Comment: Oh god... You just saved me a ton of time... :-)